# GWT Map Editor + Validator

Tags: java, gwt, bean-validation

I'm facing the following scenario:

Let B and C the beans I'm editing, having B an attribute defined as a Map:

```
public class B {
    @Valid
    private C c;

    @Valid
    private Map<String, C> map = new HashMap<String, C>();

    public Map<String, C> getMap() {
        return map;
    }

    public void setMap(Map<String, C> lista) {
        this.map = lista;
    }

    public B() {
    }

    public C getC() {
        return c;
    }

    public void setC(C c) {
        this.c = c;
    }
}

public class C {
    private Long id;

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min=10)
    private String foo;

    @Min(value=100)
    private Integer pages;

    public C() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    public void setFoo(String foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    public Integer getPages() {
        return pages;
    }

    public void setPages(Integer pages) {
        this.pages = pages;
    }
}
```

Let BEditor,CEditor and CMapEditor the editors I'm using to edit these beans and the map attribute, respectively:

```
public class BEditor extends Composite implements Editor<B> {
    CMapEditor mapEditor;

    CEditor cEditor;

    public BEditor() {
        mapEditor = new CMapEditor();

        cEditor = new CEditor();

        VerticalLayoutContainer c = new VerticalLayoutContainer();            
        c.add(mapEditor, new VerticalLayoutData(-1, 0.5));
        c.add(cEditor, new VerticalLayoutData(-1, 0.5));        

        initWidget(c);
    }

}

public class CEditor extends Composite implements Editor<C>{
    TextField fooEditor;

    IntegerSpinnerField pagesEditor;

    public CEditor() {
        fooEditor = new TextField();

        pagesEditor = new IntegerSpinnerField();
        pagesEditor.setErrorSupport(new ToolTipErrorHandler(pagesEditor));

        VerticalLayoutContainer c = new VerticalLayoutContainer();            
        c.add(fooEditor, new VerticalLayoutData(1, -1));
        c.add(pagesEditor, new VerticalLayoutData(1, -1));

        initWidget(c);
    }
}

public class CMapEditor extends Composite implements ValueAwareEditor<Map<String, C>> {
    Map<String, CEditor> ceditors = new HashMap<String, CEditor>();
    private Map<String, C> value = new HashMap<String, C>();
    private String[] locales = { "en", "es" };

    public CMapEditor() {
        TabPanel tabPanel = new TabPanel();
        for (String locale : locales) {
            CEditor cEditor = new CEditor();

            ceditors.put(locale, cEditor);

            tabPanel.add(cEditor, locale);
        }
        initWidget(tabPanel);
    }

    @Override
    public void flush() {
        for (Entry<String, C> entry : value.entrySet()) {
            CEditor cEditor = ceditors.get(entry.getKey());

            C c = entry.getValue();
            c.setFoo(cEditor.fooEditor.getValue());
            c.setPages(cEditor.pagesEditor.getValue());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(Map<String, C> value) {
        this.value = value;
        for (Entry<String, C> entry : value.entrySet()) {
            C c = entry.getValue();

            CEditor cEditor = ceditors.get(entry.getKey());
            cEditor.fooEditor.setValue(c.getFoo());
            cEditor.pagesEditor.setValue(c.getPages());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setDelegate(EditorDelegate<Map<String, C>> delegate) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPropertyChange(String... paths) {
    }
}
```

When I start the editing, the editors is filled correctly. Also the flush and the validation works OK (the validator returns all the violations that I expect), but when I set the violations in the driver, the messages of these violations are not shown in ErrorHandlers of CMapEditor components:

```
// Create the Driver
Driver driver = GWT.create(Driver.class);

public void edit(B p) {
    BEditor editor = new BEditor();
    // Initialize the driver with the top-level editor
    driver.initialize(editor);
    // Copy the data in the object into the UI
    driver.edit(p);

    // Put the UI on the screen.
    Dialog dialogBox = new Dialog();
    dialogBox.setWidget(editor);
    dialogBox.setWidth("350px");
    dialogBox.setHeight("100px");
    dialogBox.getButton(PredefinedButton.OK).addSelectHandler(new SelectEvent.SelectHandler() {            
        @Override
        public void onSelect(SelectEvent event) {
            B edited = driver.flush();

            Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
            Set violations = validator.validate(edited);
            if (!violations.isEmpty() && driver.setConstraintViolations(violations));
                List<EditorError> errors = driver.getErrors();
                //...
        }
    });
    dialogBox.show();
}
```

Is there some kind of black magic that I'm missing? Is there another way to solve this scenario?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either I don't get it (and there is something more going on that I'm missing), or you are missing a big piece of the puzzle here - your CMapEditor doesn't appear to be listening for errors, and isn't exposing its sub-paths (see ListEditor for an example) to the driver, so the fact that you called your CEditors `Editor`s doesn't mean that they are actually part of the system. You are *manually* wiring up the 'sub' editors inside CMapEditor, which means that you are now responsible for calling them when they need to be called.

The `ListEditor` extends `CompositeEditor`, and adds specific support for working in a list, and letting child editors participate in editing by telling the general editor system about them and what path they correspond to. You should consider extending CompositeEditor, probably something like `CMapEditor implements CompositeEditor<Map<String, C>, C, CEditor>`, or adding an intermediate, reusable type like `interface MapEditor<K, V, E extends Editor<? super V>> extends CompositeEditor<Map<K, V>, V, E>`, and implementing *that* to build your own CMapEditor type.

If you aren't wiring up the newly created CEditor objects so that they can talk to the delegate or driver (often by making it a `Editor` or `IsEditor` field, but also by using the `CompositeEditor.Chain` tool), then the system doesn't know about your editors, and has no way to call them. This presents another option: Make CMapEditor also implement HasEditorErrors<...> so that you get *all* errors over the entire map, and can pass them *yourself* down to the CEditor. Obviously, this will take more wiring on your part, and requires you to keep it all up to date, but that's the trade off - if you tell the editor system about the child editors, it will do it for you, but it can't do the work if it doesn't know it needs doing.

Comment: Hi Colin, implementing CompositeEditor<Map<String, C>, C, CEditor> do the trick. The problem was ConstraintViolation for subeditors has a keyed path that can't be mapped into DelegateMap; implementing CompositeEditor.getPathElement allows set a relationship between those keyed path and the subeditors. Thanks.